# Forge model with texture translation issues

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using the steps detailed at this link -- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-revit-custom-texture-map-viewer
to translate and view the Revit model with texture. But textures are not reflected in the Forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Apologizing for any inconvenience had caused to you. This is a known issue logged as `RVTLMV-1097` by our engineering team, and they are still evaluating it currently.

Therefore, please remember the RVTLMV prefixed id for future reference, and you're welcome to track updates anytime in the future via sending an email to `forge[dot]help[AT]autodesk[dot]com` with this id.

We appreciate your understanding and patience.

Comment: It would be great if you notify here when the issue is fixed. Thanks for the confirmation.